# Analyze values around a main value in 2D matrix

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have in Python, a series of 2D arrays consisting of both negative and positive values with commas. For each matrix I have to find values included in a range. Up to this point I have succeeded.
Once I have found the values with their indices, however, I have to analyze their surroundings (with for example a submatrix of known size) and depending on the values I find in the surroundings (through a condition) I assign the value 0 or 1 .

Thanks in advance everyone

Update:
I expect to get a matrix that contains zones with values of 1 or with zero values taking into account the values surrounding my main value defined with an initial condition.

A part of My matrix 2D = [0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   2   3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   3   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   3   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
]

I would like to analyze the neighborhood of the value 2. If in its neighborhood there are only 1 values then I assign a condition (eg true) or a specific value.
On the other hand, if in its surroundings there are values equal to 2 I would like to extend the search (maximum distance of 3 cells from the identified value) until the condition is satisfied (the neighborhood equal to 1).

Thanks

Comment: please proide a sample of this "series of 2D arrays".  Presumably you mean a `2d array` which is a `series of 1d arrays` (or more comonly known in `python` as a `list-of-lists`).

Comment: yes it is an array, i have a list of array with the same properties: matrix = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 3 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 2 3 3 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 3 3
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: I would like to examine the pixels around the value 2. I would like to obtain the value 1 if the pixels around all have a value equal to 1 or equal to 2

Comment: it would be better adding this to the original question.   to be consistent with this format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: okay, thanks, i think i did! :)

Comment: this is just a very long list.   A matrix is a list of lists (ie. 2 dimensions).

Comment: I think I have written it wrong, but I can confirm that it is a 2D matrix.
Unfortunately he doesn't let me attach the images.

Comment: it will be difficult to help without having an example of the correct data...